# Lambda ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, lambda, filepath

I am trying to read a file .yml inside an AWS Lambda function (Node 6.10.0).

```
console.log(__dirname + '/gameOptions.yml');
console.log(path.resolve('./gameOptions.yml'));
console.log(path.resolve('/gameOptions.yml'));
console.log('./gameOptions.yml');
console.log(process.cwd() + '/api/lib/gameOptions.yml');

let doc = yaml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('./gameOptions.yml'), 'utf8'));
```

I have tried all possibles ways to do it, but always get `ENOENT: no such file or directory`.

The file is at the same folder and it is an `.yml` so `require('')` also doesnt work.

The results for the above code are:

```
/Users\marcus\Documents\Workspace\proak-api\proak-api\api\lib/gameOptions.yml
/var/task/gameOptions.yml
/gameOptions.yml
./gameOptions.yml
/var/task/api/lib/gameOptions.yml
```

And it works locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this you need to care of two things:

**Optimize**
If you are using something to minify the code, E.g. serverless-plugin-optimize:

Include the file to not be minified.

```
  myLambda:
    handler: mySubFolder/myLambda.handler
    optimize:
      includePaths: ['mySubFolder/myFile.json']
```

Resolve the path.

```
path.resolve(process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT, '_optimize', process.env.AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME, 'mySubFolder/myFile.json')
```

If you dont use minify, you also need to require the .yml file into the Lambda, to compile into the function.

**Require** require('file.yml') gives you an error. So you let to:

```
var fs = require('fs')
  , yaml = require('js-yaml');

    require.extensions['.yaml'] = 
    require.extensions['.yml'] = function(module, filename) {
      var content = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
      // Parse the file content and give to module.exports
      content = yaml.load(content);
      module.exports = content;
    };
```